# Fortify Warning - Unsupported JVM

Tags: java, fortify

I am using Fortify source code analyzer to analyze security issues in my Java code.

It gives me warning

" Source Code Analysis Engine is running under an unsupported Java Virtual Machine (Sun Microsystems Inc. 1.6.0_27)"

I couldn't find supported version from help docs. Could you please tell me which version does Fortify support? I am using Audit workbench version 5.2.1.0002. I am running under Ubuntu.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very old version of SCA that came out before Fortify supported the 1.6 JVM.

You have several options:

1) run SCA using an older JVM (like 1.5)

2) Upgrade to the latest version of SCA, which you should be able to do with your current license through the Fortify Customer Portal. However this will be changing soon. We are in the process of moving everything to the HP distribution framework.

3) Ignore the error and trust that the Java JVM is truly backwards compatible.

-Larry